# Linq List to share all except duplicate with certain status

Tags: c#, linq

Ok, folks.  I have a list that contains two properties: ID and Status.
ex)
1001 Shipped
1002 Shipped
1003 Shipped
1003 Cancelled

From this list, I need to get all EXCEPT duped items with 'Cancelled' status. Essentially, see if they are duped (would only be duped once) and if so, do not include the 'Cancelled' one in the new list.  So the new list should contain 1001, 1002 and 1003.

So that if I had: 
1001 Cancelled
1002 Cancelled
1003 Cancelled
1004 Cancelled
The list would contain 1001, 1002, 1003 and 1004.  I'm able to construct this initial list using linq in C# (as in "Items.GroupBy(product => new { product.ProductID, product.Status }).ToList()" ), but cannot proceed any further.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what rules you apply to select items. You have selected all items both from first and second lists. What you are trying to select - whole object or only id? What if object has several statuses?

Comment: From first list, I selected item 1, 2, and 3 (not 4). 4 was not selected because it's ID is a dupe AND 'cancelled'. From second list, all are picked up because the IDs are not duped.

Comment: There is no 4 in first list - there is 1001, 1002 and 1003 - you have selected all these ids

Comment: Yes but it does not have 1001, 1002, 1003 and 1003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From rules which you specified, simple selecting unique product ids with `Distinct()` will do the job:

```
Items.Select(product => product.ProductID).Distinct()
```

That gives you `1001, 1002, 1003` for the first sample and `1001, 1002, 1003, 1004` for the second sample.

---

If you don't want to select ids of products which have *last* status as cancelled and timeline is represented only by order of items in your initial list:

```
 Items.GroupBy(product => product.ProductID)
      .Where(g => g.Last().Status != "Cancelled")
      .Select(g => g.Key)
```

Comment: Yes, Sergy thank you.  I had tried that previously.  The issue is that  when the Product object is passed on for consumption, the 1003 product that is passed cannot be the 'Cancelled' one.  In needs to be the 'Shipped' one.  Using Distinct, there's a chance that the 'Cancelled' one gets selected since the order in the list is unpredictable to me.  Sorry, I guess I oversimplified my initial question.

Comment: @bobj you have pointed that you are selecting only ids of products. Probably you have other fields in your product class. Maybe update date, or record id (I assume you actually have some class which references product - not product itself) or something like that. So that it would be possible to select object with latest status. You should update question with better samples which include different statuses for same product, and at least one product which should not be selected

Comment: @bobj also you are saying that 1003 product cannot be in the cancelled state, but your first sample clearly states that you are selecting product which is in cancelled state

Comment: I will dig into the Product class to see if there is such info, good lead.  To clear things up, let's call them the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th objects.  The third object (1003, shipped) is good but 4th object (1003, cancelled) is bad.  Sorry for the confusion :/

Comment: @bobj please check updated answer and say if it's what you are trying to achieve. If it's not what you need, then please specify how it differs from expected results

Comment: Will do, Sergey.  I appreciate your help tremendously!